# Windows Security login form?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, desktop

Do you know the awesome looking form of Windows Live that asks you for your cerdentials?
[Gmail Notifier](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_windows.html) has it too, somehow.

Is there any way I can invoke something like this in my application?

---

BEHOLD!
[image: BEHOLD]

---

I wish to use this dialog for local authentication on a desktop app.

Comment: Can you please explain where the credentials are supposed to come from?

Comment: I mean - what is this supposed to authenticate with?

Comment: Oh... Stored credentials in a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into calling `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials`:

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials
>   function creates and displays a
>   configurable dialog box that allows
>   users to supply credential information
>   by using any credential provider
>   installed on the local computer.

But there is more to this than simply displaying the dialog and recieving / acting on input - you'll most likely be required to register an authentication provider on the system, among some other things I'm not entirely competent with explaining in any detail! Might give you a decent starting ground though.

**UPDATE:**

Oded compensated for my laziness and supplied the pinvoke.net link displaying definitions for this to be used in a managed environment:

[CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials PInvoke.NET Link](http://pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials&namespace=%5BAll%5D)

Comment: And the pInvoke for this function: http://pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials&namespace=[All]

Comment: ...any time. Glad it helped. :)